# Tikz creating an array with for each

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code

```
,tex
\newcommand{\matmul}[3]{
\def#1{}
\foreach \i in {#3}{
\def\temp{}
\foreach \j in {#2}{
\pgfmathparse{\i*\j}
\xdef\temp{\temp,\pgfmathresult}
}
\xdef#1{#1,{\temp}}
}
}
\matmul{\yeet}{1,3}{2,4}
$\yeet$
```

And this output

```
,,2,0,6.0,,4.0,12.0
```

I can't seem to think of a solution where I don't get double commas and commas at the start of the list

This is the output I want

```
2.0,6.0,4.0,12.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard thingy: introduce counters and add a comma only if the counter is greater than 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\matmul}[3]{%
\foreach \i [count=\ci] in {#3}{%
\foreach \j [count=\cj] in {#2}{%
\pgfmathparse{\i*\j}%
\ifnum\cj=1%
\xdef\temp{\pgfmathresult}%
\else
\xdef\temp{\temp,\pgfmathresult}%
\fi
}%
\ifnum\ci=1%
\xdef#1{{\temp}}%
\else
\xdef#1{#1,{\temp}}%
\fi
}%
}
\begin{document}
test:\matmul{\yeet}{1,3}{2,4}$\yeet$ \typeout{\yeet}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
{2.0,6.0},{4.0,12.0}
```

It would be great if you could consider posting complete examples like the above in the future.

Comment: Thank you again :D